# Core Data. Detect same object?

Tags: ios, core-data, nsstring, nsmanagedobject, equality

I have 2 `Core Data` objects of the same type. I got them via different ways.

At the same time these objects have an `NSString` field (identifier).

So what is better?

1)compare objects via `isEqual:`

2)compare objects via `==` (is it possible in general?)

3)compare objects' fields via `isEqualToString:`?

Comment: If the objects have the same identifier then just compare that?

Comment: Have you already fetched the objects? Is this in a predicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, never use `==` on objects. Always use `isEqual:`.

If you're using a predicate then you can use `LIKE` on the identifier.

Comment: I wouldn't say "never". There are some cases where I compare the pointers to test if it's the same object.

Comment: As @Wain stated, option #1 is the right answer in this case.  Let the `NSManagedObject` implementation of `-isEqual:` answer the question.

Comment: Why "LIKE"?  That would treat ? and * as patterns.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to determine whether or not two objects are the semantically equal and you can describe what equality looks like for that type, then use isEqual.  For example, if you have a Person class, you might define equality based on SSN (in the US) or something equally unique.

If you are trying to determine that two objects have something specific in common, but it doesn't necessarily imply that they are equal (for example, using the same Person example, if you want find out if two instances have the same last name), compare the attributes using isEqualToString:.  It would not make sense to put this comparison into isEqual for the type.

If you are trying to find out if you have two NSManagedObject instances from your persistent store that are actually the same object fetched via different NSManagedObjectContexts, use the objectID for comparison.